# JavaScript: What should I return to note this function as incorrect input?

Tags: javascript, return

If the user inputs 1 in this example, I want the function to stop, so should I return **true**, or **NULL**, or **1**, or **0**...or does it really matter?

```
function foo() {
    // incorrect input
    if (bar === 1) {
        return true;
    }
    // correct input
    else {
        arr.push(bar);
    }
}
```

I know in C, 0 is returned for programs with correct input, but for programs with incorrect input they return 1, 2, 3....
Not sure what the protocol is for JavaScript.

Comment: Depends on how `foo` is being called, and what it would normally return on correct input. A plain `return` might work

Comment: So the return statement doesn't matter, for a *failure* in this case?

Comment: How are you using the function?

Comment: No not really unless you want to return it to another function and do something for a the failure

Comment: Return whatever is meaningful to you and the program, it's your function you decide on what the things returned mean

Comment: If the function doesn't fail, the else statement pushes the input to an array...lemme update my code to reflect that.

Comment: If your function's parameters are not of the correct type, you can throw a `TypeError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what the context of this function is. Are you using the return value somewhere else? If not you can just use `return` to stop the function from executing:

```
if (bar === 1) {
    return;
}
```

And if you are using the return value somewhere else and want to act on the failure you can just return false or anything and then check if that value exists.

In your updated context you can just use the following code and it will push to the array if `true` and do nothing if `false`

```
if (bar !== 1) {
    arr.push(bar);
}
```

Comment: No, it's not being used anywhere else, just a simple failure

Comment: In that case you can just use `return`

Comment: Originally, I just wanted to return **NULL**, but I saw a post on StackOverflow that said NULL should only be returned in very specific circumstances. At the end of the day it doesn't matter what it's returned since the return statement is a failure, but I'd rather do things properly.

Comment: I like what you did, that means I have to write less code. I'll implement that into my program if I can.

Comment: @00Saad And IMO `return null` if you want to. In some specific situation it may be a bad idea but if you need to for your situation that's what you need to do.

Comment: @00Saad Glad I could help. Happy coding :)

Comment: At the end of the day I can return the entire text of War and Peace and the program will work, but I'd rather do things properly while I'm still at the pre-schooler level of JS instead of learning the hard way when I have actual experience under my belt.

Answer (score 0):

You can either just return or if it is nested in a loop and you want to move on to the next item, you can also use 'continue;' so it doesn't terminate your loop